# Do the raiders ever cap out on weaponry?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've noticed that the raiders are getting better and better weaponry each time they raid? Will this eventually stop? Is there some upper limit or will I eventually need the best weaponry in the game just to fend them off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they won't stop coming. First they all start carrying machetes, then pistols, later on hunting rifles. Then a few of them start carrying Laser Pistols. Either Laser Rifles or Plasma Pistols come next, followed by the other. Then it was the Plasma Rifles. And now it is the Railway Guns.

Don't know what will come next.

The door will only hold them for a few seconds, so you can prepare and get your best soldiers to the vault door and the next rooms.

Comment: By the way, I would give my suggestion on this. I have a reactor room and a dinner underneath my vault entrance. Those guys in those rooms have pretty high S and/or A values and have nearly lvl 50 through their work. I keep them upstairs, to let them rush to the vault quickly. This way I don't have to equip the vault entrance at all and waste my dwellers.

Comment: @Ionic I stumbled into the same behavior. They just run into the room and die quickly.

Comment: @OrionAdrian Yes probably the best solution to hold back the raiders.

Comment: I suspect this to not be true. I have a old vault and the raiders still attack mostly with pistols and swords (the laser pistol once in a while) while a new vault got its first raiders attack with pistols only!

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been different than what feco describe.

My older vault still only get swords and pistols holding raiders attacks. There's at least one that had a laser pistol but the last 4 were a mix of bullet pistols and swords, one actually was swords only as you can see below!

[image]

The best weapon that vault has is the [Magnetron 4000](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Magnetron_4000).

I got a [Gaitlin laser](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gatling_laser_%28Fallout_Shelter%29) (it might be [one of the better](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Amplified_Gatling_laser) version, I can't remember exactly, will update asap) from a lunchbox in my new vault and the raiders never used swords, they are attacking with bullet pistols already (the 2 attacks so far, don't play it much compared to my oldest).

I suspect that it is either based on how much damage your best weapon does or its type (see this [list of weapons](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_weapons) and note that the Gaitlin is heavy while the Magnetron is a rifle) that makes the raiders become more difficult.

At least is seems more important than the age of the vault.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility, but my experiences over 5 vaults have been that they always start with swords and go up, as in the other answer, including the vault where I got a Fat Man in my first lunch box.