# When do Deathclaws start attacking your vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've been playing the Android version for a few days now, and have 33 Dwellers (slow growth FTW?) and I've noticed that I've never been attacked by the Deathclaws that I've heard about.

Do the Deathclaws and other stronger enemies like Raiders with more guns or molerats only show up after a certain number of hours of Vault existence, or perhaps after your Vault reaches a certain number of Dwellers?

Comment: It was about 50 to 60 dwellers when they started showing up for me. Dunno how long in game time.

Comment: I second Ross, and even with that many dwellers, the deathclaws reached the bottom floor before finally being wiped out (thankfully they didn't spend long enough in any one room to kill)

Comment: Good question. Knowing this _could_ affect the way people play, as staying a certain size and gearing up before expanding would be more important if it's based on dwellers rather than time.

Comment: [Related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/225279/61395)

Comment: I suspect that it's based on the number of Dwellers you have. I noticed that molerats started showing up when I hit 20 Dwellers. Haven't seen any new enemies since then; I've been holding at 34 for a few days now and improving my weapons array through Wasteland missions.

Answer (score 11):

Deathclaws start showing up after you have 60 or more Dwellers in your Vault (the tipping point may be 61). They are attracted by Radio signals and the Door opening.

Comment: So far this seems to be accurate. I've been sitting at 59 Dwellers, and haven't seen any Deathclaws yet. (My hope is to get high level Dwellers to bring back some really good weapons from the Wasteland so that I'm as prepared as possible.

Comment: I have been attacked at 61, and haven't been attacked since I went back down to 60 (admittedly that was just this morning). I've never been attacked by deathclaws below 60.

Comment: Having been sitting at around 60 pretty consistently while I level my vault, I'm pretty sure 61 is the trigger. I've had them show up at 61 as soon as a lunchbox dweller showed up. But haven't had any at 60.

Comment: Seems to be considerably lower in Survival-Mode? Or maybe they lowered the cap with the latest update? I reached 40 dwellers in my survival-mode vault and got two consecutive Deathclaw attacks which killed a *lot* of my dwellers.

Comment: I also got a Dethclaw attack, but fortunately they haven't killed no one in my Vault. Instead, I've used all my Stimpaks. :( @bummzack

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw_(Fallout_Shelter)#Notes), **Deathclaws start attacking your Vault when you've reached 60 dwellers, or 35 dwellers on Survival mode.** *The chances of an attack increase as you open your Vault's door, or having an active Radio Room.*

Comment: This is the new correct answer.

Comment: I was going to correct this to say "survival mode", rather than "hardcore mode", but then realized that it's a direct quote from the source, which uses the wrong term.

Comment: The attacks also stop if you drop the population back down.  I pushed my population up to unlock all the buildings, then promptly evicted them all out.  I don't plan to face deathclaws until the first 3-4 rooms are filled with E10 dwellers levelled from 1 to 50.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Fallout wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw_(Fallout_Shelter)#Notes) :

> According to in-game information, deathclaws are more likely to attack your vault if you open the vault doors and if you have a radio station.

I have no more accurate data for now.

Answer (score 2):

I did read somewhere that you needed a certain amount of dwellers. Then the variables kick into play.

The variables are: Vault door being opened and Radio Room brodcasts