# What happens to my vault when I ban dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I just recently hit 60 dwellers in my vault, and as soon as I did, there was a group of feral ghouls that attacked me.

Now I've read that when you get to "X" amount of dwellers, the difficulty increases such as different enemies attacking you. But what happens if I start banning dwellers from my vault to get it below a certain number?

Do the rooms I built that require a certain number of villagers automatically get destroyed? Will the new enemies still spawn and attack? Does the difficulty decrease?

Right now most of my dwellers have very low stats, even when I have armor equipped. Currently I have a male and female dweller training their stats, my ultimate goal is to have 10 on each stat then start breeding for better dwellers.

Comment: Be aware that even when you breed two all-10's stat dwellers, they won't have children with so good stats. They should have the normal range of skill stats, you will barely get at least one 4... (if something did not changed in last month's updates, if there were any). You still need to train all dwellers from a scratch, it won't be any big difference if hatched from 10's or from 1's.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can ban a bunch of Dwellers to fall below the threshold where these attacks start occurring to get them to stop, as seen in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/233095/162442):

> Deathclaws won't show up if you have less than 60 dwellers in your Vault (60 exactly may also be okay). So, aside from never opening your Vault door and never using the Radio, one possibility is to send of your less productive dwellers out into the wilderness and let them die (or just remove some of the dwellers killed in Deathclaw attacks) until your total population is 60 or less.

As for whether rooms will become re-locked if you drop beneath the required number, it looks like they *will not*, according to the same answer linked above.

> It's worth noting that rooms you've unlocked stay unlocked even if your population takes a dip.

All of the information provided above has been verified by others online.

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3kt3ve/question_is_the_change_past_60_dwellers_a/):

> Drop back below the threshold, and the attacks stop. Rooms you unlock will stay unlocked, so you don't have to worry about remodeling before dropping back down.

And from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/41drhm/do_you_guys_have_any_strategies_for_what_you/cz6zkgo/):

> Yes, they stay unlocked.
>
> Source: I had a 60 pop survival vault burn to the ground, 5 survivors. Was still able to build nuclear reactor room.
>
> I highly recommend getting up to the reactor (power storage) and dropping your pop to under 35 to prevent death claw attacks.